# In Civilization 5, how may turns are there for each Game Pace setting?

Tags: civilization-5

I'm about to start a new game, and I'm using the Advanced Setup to customize the game a little. Does anyone know the number of turns for each of the 4 Game Pace settings to get to 2050?

- Marathon = ?
- Epic = ?
- Standard = 500 turns
- Quick = ?

Or is it not that simple?

More generally, is there a detailed guide anywhere to what all the settings on the Advanced Setup screen affect? Some have explanatory tooltips but some don't!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

CIV5GameSpeeds.xml has all the information about what the different game speeds do.  Adding up the number of turns for each speed gives us:

- Marathon = 1500 turns
- Epic = 750 turns
- Standard = 500 turns
- Quick = 330 turns

You can also disable time victory, in which case there is an unlimited number of turns. I'm not aware of a guide to all the advanced setup options.  Most of them I think affect the random generation of the world.  If you have questions about a specific one, feel free to create another question.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I wanted a bit more than a Standard game so I went for Epic. Marathon may be a bit too long!

Comment: I had the impression that in addition to having more turns, slower games also had things take longer to build and research. Or is this a misunderstanding?

Comment: @Nzall, no, you're correct.  Research, production costs, etc. are scaled, so in Marathon they'd take three times as long as normal.  What isn't scaled is moves, so playing in Marathon effectively gives you three times as many moves around the map, which is worth considering if you're going for a Domination victory.