# Is there a way in civ 5 to go past 2050

Tags: civilization-5

Is there a known way to essentially make it so the game never ends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to get around the time limit:

- Turn the time limit off!  From the main menu, click "Single Player" and then "Advanced Setup."  From here, you can remove any of the victory conditions, including "time."
- Ignore the time limit!  When any victory condition is achieved, including time, there's a button that says "One... More... Turn..." and clicking this will allow you to continue the game.

Do note that if you care about your score, both of these are bad options.  Turning off the time victory option can make you go far into the future, and your score is computed partially based on how long it took you to win.  In the "One... More... Turn..." case, the score is recorded when you win, and never afterwards.

You can also make it *feel* like the game is taking forever by adjusting the game speed, in the "Advanced Setup" menu.  Setting the game pace to "Epic" or "Marathon" will give you more turns with lowered productivity per-turn.

Comment: Ok cool, so if I change the time to say Epic, that just means the time that is going by in terms of years is slower, but is the time it takes to build things and move places slower?

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau, There are more turns in Epic and Marathon, but things take longer.  The effect of this is that you essentially get more time to move units around the map.  The game is kinda/sorta balanced so that the increase in turns is proportional to the increased time it takes to research/produce.    The turn limits per time scale can be found in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9186/13845)